# How do I calculate the p-value from an ANOVA from R-Studio?

Tags: r, regression, anova

[image]
Don't really know how to interpret this! I am so confused and I tried to follow the examples but I am confused.

Comment: Is your question "how do I calculate the p-value?" or "how do I interpret this table?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that, without knowing more about your model, whatever you are testing is not significant. If you are used to seeing output from other programs, the `Pr(F)` column may seem confusing (it is just the $p$ value). It is the probability of the $F$ statistic you obtained from your test on $(1, 143)$ degrees of freedom. The other columns and rows provide additional information, but I imagine the components I identified are what matter most to you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so for clarification, how would I go about hypothesis testing which one is a better model? Model 1 & 2 were both linear models, where model 2 had 1 of the covariates removed. I found a "P-value from F-ratio' calculator online but idk what anything means! Would the F-ratio be 0.8486 in this case and what is the df numerator and denominator?

Comment: Based on your comment and the notion that you are making a model comparison, the addition of on more predictor does not significantly improve model fit in your case, $F(1,143) = 0.85, p = .359$.